# How to replace dynamic exception specifications: throw(...)

Tags: c++, exception, c++17, throw

I am working on a project that uses a legacy library which uses function definitions like

```
void func() throw(some_exception);
```

Since [dynamic exception specifications](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec) are removed in C++17 I am wondering how to address this problem.

1. [P0003R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0003r0.html) suggests to replace

   ```
   void func() throw(some_exception)
   {
       /* body */ 
   }
   ```

   with something like

   ```
   void func()
   {
       try
       {
           /* body */
       }
       catch(const some_exception&) {
          throw;
       }
   }
   ```

   However, I do not have access to the source code (only the header files).
2. So I am left with trying to "fix" the function definition in the header. So e.g. I could write

   ```
   void func() noexcept(false);
   ```

   But when the function throws an exception, my application still terminates.

How can I change the function definition in the header files or possibly adjust my own project (the places where i use `func`) to obtain the same behaviour as `throw(some_exception)` had before C++17?

Comment: I don't see what the replacement using `try`/`catch` adds. Maybe adding a `catch(...) { std::terminate(); }` or something would be closer to the original intention.

Comment: `void func() noexcept(false);` should work.  If your application is terminating it could be you fail to catch the expectation and the call stack rewinds all the way back up to the top without finding an appropriate handler.

Comment: @NathanOliver how do i catch it? I tried `try{ func() } catch(...) {  }` but my app still terminates.

Comment: Please make a minimal testcase for the 2) case.

Comment: @Phil-ZXX Please share a [mcve]. If the change doesn't work then the problem is more probably complicated than the question implies and involves code not shown here.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I would normally share a working example, but since I am working with a black-box (no access to `func`'s source code), I was trying to get some high-level advice. I will try to get a working example though.

Comment: Is `func` in a precompiled library? How was it compiled and how are you compiling your code? This may be an ABI problem. C++ doesn't always play well when mixing binaries compiled in different ways.

Comment: You link P0003R0 then you claim it says to write code different than thwat P0003R0 says.  Do you not understand what P0003R0 is asking you to do there?

Comment: As @FrançoisAndrieux denoted already, in C++ code coming from different compilers (even same compiler, but different version, sometimes even same compiler, same version, but differing compilation flags) can result in incompatible ABI - for instance the layout for even such simple classes like `std::string` or `std::exception` might differ. The compilers might have used different exception models (dwarf2, SJLJ, SEH). All this could lead to programme and the library not being able to interact one with another, and the exception specification *might* yet be your least problem...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just remove the dynamic exception specification. That's all you need to do.

C++ is not Java; in C++, all functions are (at a language level) assumed to throw anything unless they are tagged `noexcept`. As such, if you remove the exception specification, it will work exactly as it did before.

Comment: OP says he/she tried replacing it with `noexcept(false)` which is the default in almost all cases. So it seems he/she has already tried this. Unless there's something about `noexcept(false)` that would cause a problem where no exception specification at all would work.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: "*OP says he/she tried replacing it with noexcept(false) which is the default in almost all cases.*" Is it? In C++17, there was a change made to the function type system to include the `noexcept` status in the function's type. Now, I haven't read the details of it, but it *may* be that putting even `noexcept(false)` there affects the ABI, whereas putting nothing there ought to be ABI-neutral.